# Inflating same view through another xml file. Do I need unique id?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-view

[image: This is my initial layout]

This is my initial layout of which the following EditText with id: assign_edit and weight_edit are part of. The name of this layout is new_class_container.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/assign_edit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:hint="@string/example_assign"
         android:singleLine="true"
         android:inputType="textCapWords"
         android:layout_weight="1">
     </EditText>

    <EditText
         android:id="@+id/weight_edit"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/example_weight"
         android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
         android:gravity="center_horizontal"
         android:inputType="number"
         android:singleLine="true">
     </EditText>        

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout that I want to inflate is named new_class. In this layout, I copy pasted the exact same EditText's mentioned above. The following is my java file

public class DefiningClass extends Activity {

```
private ViewGroup mContainerView;
private EditText assignName;
private EditText assignWeight;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.new_class_container);

    mContainerView = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu add){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, add);
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.btn_save:
            //INSERT INSTRUCTIONS TO SAVE
            String str = assignName.getText().toString();
            Toast msg = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            msg.show();
            break;
        case R.id.btn_add:
            //findViewById(android.R.id.empty).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            addItem();
            break;
        default: 
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);   
}

private void addItem() {
    final ViewGroup newView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(
            R.layout.new_class, mContainerView, false);

    assignName = (EditText) newView.findViewById(R.id.assign_edit);
    assignWeight = (EditText) newView.findViewById(R.id.weight_edit);

    mContainerView.addView(newView, 0);
    }
}
```

I put a Toast in my btn_save to see the work it does. When I run it, it only shows the most recent EditText. How can I make it so the toast recognizes all the edittexts that I have "inflated" and placed in it. For instance, if I had three edittexts, first said Hello, 2nd, Welcome, 3rd, Bye. The toast only shows Bye and not the other two.

What can I do for it to recognize the other two? When I save it in the future I want all the edittexts to be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/assign_edit"/> // missing @+
```

Your `findViewById` looks for a view with the id in the current infalted layout.

So having the same ids in different layout xml files is not a problem.

Check the topic id in the below link

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

An ID need not be unique throughout the entire tree, but it should be unique within the part of the tree you are searching (which may often be the entire tree, so it's best to be completely unique when possible).

Comment: How do I separate all the edittexts? Because the user creates them "dynamically". How would I reference them in the java file separately? For instance...the first edittext says Business, the 2nd Personal, 3rd Family. 

 `for(int i = 0; i < DON'T KNOW YET WHAT GOES HERE; i++)  {
  EditText[i] et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.);  
 }`

Would that take care of it?

Comment: @YashChitneni sorry you can't do like that. `EditText ed = new EditText(ActivityName.this)` this is how it is initialized

Comment: @YashChitneni and remember that is only initialized you need to add it to root layout in xml or to the activity. If you are still confused edit your post and add more details

Comment: I worked on it for a bit and I wrote the issue, I am currently having in regards with my toast message. It is only recognizing the last inflated edittext. I did the edits up there. Could you let me know why it only recognizes the last inflated edittext? Thanks a lot for helping me so far.

Comment: @YashChitneni you get value only from 1 edittext. that is why you see only one value in Toast. Also i see no reason why you need to infalte a different layout makes no sense. 1 Activity inflate once

Comment: @YashChitneni you only get value from 1 editext `String str = assignName.getText().toString();` How do you expect to see value from other edittext also?

Comment: I inflate it because the user inflates the edittexts to his or her requirement. I also inflate another layout because I didn't paste the part of my initial layout which consists of a textview and another edittext. 

Regarding the 2nd comment that is where I was stuck, how could I ensure to get values from all these edittexts that are being created dynamically? That's how I had the initial question on would I have to create new unique ids and if yes how I would do that?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44044/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-yash-chitneni)

Comment: @YashChitneni join the chat @ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44044/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-yash-chitneni